# Error al obtener nombres con apostrofes al usar regex java android

Tags: java, android, regex

Tengo un problema con este código regex para obtener cadenas de texto con apostrofes obtenidas a través de un streaming. El código que utilizo es este:

```
public static Map<String, String> parseMetadata(String metaString) {
    Map<String, String> metadata = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String[] metaParts = metaString.split(";");
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^([a-zA-Z]+)=\\'([^\\']*)\\'$");
    Matcher m;

    for (int i = 0; i < metaParts.length; i++) {
        m = p.matcher(metaParts[i]);
        if (m.find()) {
            metadata.put(m.group(1), m.group(2));
             Log.d("MAP", String.valueOf(metadata));
        }
    }

    return metadata;
}
```

Esta parte del codigo es la que me da problemas

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^([a-zA-Z]+)=\\'([^\\']*)\\'$");
```

Y este es un ejemplo de texto (sólo puede haber un único título en el string):

> ```
> StreamTitle='The Swirling Eddies - Don't Ask Me How I Feel';
> ```

El problema es que si hay una canción que tenga el titulo **con apóstrofe**, no me la muestra y los títulos con guiones, corchetes o acentos si.

Por ejemplo si el titulo es así: **`Can't play`**, no me muestra la cadena de texto, y lo que estoy buscando es que se muestre con todo y apóstrofe.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59034/discussion-between-mariano-and-quimbo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En regex no es necesario de escapar `'` con `\`. Entonces, si el formato que estas buscando es algo como:

```
title='Can\'t be'
```

el `Pattern` sería

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^([a-zA-Z]+)='(.*)'$");
```

Eso te da en grupo 1 el nombre del tag y en grupo 2 el contenido entre los `'`.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, el texto que busco seria mostrarlo con todo y apostrofe. Por ejemplo Can't Be en vez de mostrarse con la barra inversa.

Comment: en el grupo 2 de este regex el punto encuentra cualquier carácter, excepto un salto de linea?

Comment: Después de lo conversado en el chat, vimos que se está recibiendo un único título (y no múltiples). Esta es la solución correcta.